# I'm not able to remove Alpha(Transparency) on OpenGL Graphic

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opengl

I don't solve the transparency problem for 1 week. I wanto remove all transparency settings on my 3d graphic that I draw, I just wanna solid no-transparent 3d graphic here.I putted my graphic's link which is related to my current result. I've tried a lot stuff that I saw on the internet, but I didn't get a success thanks already

[image]

INITIAL SETTINGS

```
            simpleOpenGlControl1.InitializeContexts();
            Gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
            Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
            Gl.glLoadIdentity();
            Glu.gluPerspective(25, (double)width / (double)height, 0.5f, 5000.0f);
```

PAINT EVENT

```
            double olcek3d_gen1 = obj.genislikDeger1 / pictureBox1.Width;
            double olcek3d_gen2 = obj.genislikDeger2 / pictureBox1.Width;
            double olcek3d_gen3 = obj.genislikDeger3 / pictureBox1.Width;
            double olcek3d_gen4 = obj.genislikDeger4 / pictureBox1.Width;

            double olcek3d_yuk1 = obj.yukselikDeger1 / pictureBox1.Width;
            double olcek3d_yuk2 = obj.yukselikDeger2 / pictureBox1.Width;
            double olcek3d_yuk3 = obj.yukselikDeger3 / pictureBox1.Width;
            double olcek3d_yuk4 = obj.yukselikDeger4 / pictureBox1.Width;

            double olcek_derinlik = obj.L / pictureBox1.Width;
 
            Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT); //clear buffers to preset values


           
            Gl.glClearColor(0, 0,0, 0);
            //Gl.glColorMask(1,1,1,1);



           
            Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

            Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_LIGHTING);
            Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_LIGHT0);

          


            Gl.glBlendFunc(Gl.GL_ONE, Gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
           
            Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
          
            Gl.glLoadIdentity();                 // load the identity matrix
                          // load the identity 
            Gl.glTranslated(left_right,up_down,sabit3D);


            //Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
           
            Gl.glRotated(xrot -= 1.5, 0.0f, -0.1f, 0.0f);
          

            //rotate on y
            //Gl.glRotated(zrot += 0.5, 0, 0, 1); //rotate on z



            //face 1.0
            Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);    //start drawing GL_QUADSis the connection mode
                Gl.glColor3d(0, 0,0);
            Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
            Gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen1, 0, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen1, olcek3d_yuk1, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, olcek3d_yuk1, 0);
                Gl.glEnd();
            
          


            //face 2.0 görünen açıdan sağdaki
            Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(70, 70, 70);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen1, 0, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen1, 0, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen1, olcek3d_yuk1, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen1, olcek3d_yuk1, 0);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face 3.0 ön yüzey
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(80, 80, 80);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen1, 0, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen1, olcek3d_yuk1, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, olcek3d_yuk1, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face 4.0 arka yüzey

                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(90, 90, 90);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, olcek3d_yuk1, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, olcek3d_yuk1, 0);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face 5.0 üst yüzey

                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
            Gl.glBlendFunc(Gl.GL_ZERO, Gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

            Gl.glColor3ub(80,80,80);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, olcek3d_yuk1, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen1, olcek3d_yuk1, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen1, olcek3d_yuk1, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, olcek3d_yuk1, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face 6.0 // kırmızı çizgi sorunu olabilir

                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3d(110,110,110);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen1, 0, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen1, 0, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face 1.1

                /*Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);    //start drawing GL_QUADSis the connection mode
                Gl.glColor3ub(0,0,0);

                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen2, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen2, 0, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
                Gl.glEnd();*/

                //face 2.1
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(70, 70, 70);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen2, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen2, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen2, 0, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen2, 0, 0);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face 3.1
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(80, 80, 80);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen2, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen2, 0, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face 4.1
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(90,90,90);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face cover.1 çizgi level
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(80,80,80);

                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen1, 0, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen2, 0, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen2, 0, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen1, 0, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glEnd();


            if (sev.Value == 2)
            {   
                //face 5.1
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(85,85,85);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen2, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen2, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glEnd();
            }
                
            
            if (sev.Value>=3)
            {
                //face 1.2

                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);    //start drawing GL_QUADSis the connection mode
                Gl.glColor3ub(85,85,85);

                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2+olcek3d_yuk3), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen3, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen3, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2 , 0);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face 2.2
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(70, 70, 70);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen3, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen3, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen3, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen3, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2 , 0);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face 3.2
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(90, 90, 90);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen3, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen3, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face 4.2
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(85,85,85);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * olcek3d_yuk2, 0);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face kapak.2
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(80, 80, 80);

                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen2, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk1), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen3, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk1), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen3, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk1), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen2, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk1), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glEnd();



                if (sev.Value == 3) {
                    //face 5.2
                    Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                    Gl.glColor3ub(85,85,85);
                    Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), 0);
                    Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen3, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), 0);
                    Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen3, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), olcek_derinlik);
                    Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), olcek_derinlik);
                    Gl.glEnd();
                    
                }
                    

            }
            if (sev.Value == 4)
            {
                //face 1.3

                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);    //start drawing GL_QUADSis the connection mode
                Gl.glColor3ub(85,85,85);

                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3+olcek3d_yuk4), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen4, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3+olcek3d_yuk4), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen4, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2+olcek3d_yuk3), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), 0);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face 2.3
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(70,70,70);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen4, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3+olcek3d_yuk4), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen4, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3+olcek3d_yuk4),olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen4, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen4, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), 0);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face 3.3
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(90, 90, 90);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3 + olcek3d_yuk4), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen4, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3 + olcek3d_yuk4),olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen4, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face 4.3
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(85,85,85);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3 + olcek3d_yuk4), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3 + olcek3d_yuk4), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3), 0);
                Gl.glEnd();
                //face 5.3
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(85,85,85);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3+olcek3d_yuk4), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen4, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3 + olcek3d_yuk4), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen4, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3 + olcek3d_yuk4), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(0, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk2 + olcek3d_yuk3 + olcek3d_yuk4), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glEnd();

                //face kapak.2
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                Gl.glColor3ub(80, 80, 80);

                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen3, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk1+olcek3d_yuk2), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen4, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk1+ olcek3d_yuk2), 0);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen4, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk1+ olcek3d_yuk2), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glVertex3d(olcek3d_gen3, -1 * (olcek3d_yuk1+ olcek3d_yuk2), olcek_derinlik);
                Gl.glEnd();
```

Comment: You missed to enable the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test): `GL.Enable(GL.DEPTH_TEST)`

Comment: i didn't  work bro

Comment: Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH)

Comment: You have to be more specific. What exactly does not work? Doesn't anything change after enabling the depth test? Do you even have a depth buffer? How do you create the OpenGL window?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that,  after adding Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
my box is blacked out like this
https://hizliresim.com/vgnllp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to enable the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test). When the depth test is enabled, then you have to clear the depth buffer, too:

```
Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPHT_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT); 

Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```